# Distinct use in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

I have the following query in codeigniter
The idea is to only get distinct rows - the column I want to use this on is called club_id - any ideas how to do this in codeigniter so only one offer shows per club_id?

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->limit($limit);
$this->db->where("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`end_date`) > ".time());
$q = $this->db->get('offers');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the column in the select method like the following

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select("club_id")
$this->db->limit($limit);
$this->db->where("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`end_date`) > ".time());
$q = $this->db->get('offers');
```

Comment: If this is what Gaz is asking, then this is correct. I can't tell if Gaz is wanting to join offers to a club table. +1 to you.